# Nest - Need help on elastic response mocking

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "filter#count_stats" : {
      "doc_count" : 30,
      "lterms#Name1" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : 53986,
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "sterms#Name2" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "Soft",
                  "doc_count" : 7,
                },
                {
                  "key" : "Health",
                  "doc_count" : 5
                },
                 ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : 40127,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "sterms#Name3" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "XYZ",
                  "doc_count" : 3
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IAggregate> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IAggregate>();
        var keyedAggregate1 = new KeyedBucket<object>(dictionary) { Key = "Soft", DocCount = 7};
        var keyedAggregate2 = new KeyedBucket<object>(dictionary) { Key = "Health", DocCount = 8 };

        var keyedAggregate3 = new KeyedBucket<object>(dictionary) { Key = "XYZ", DocCount = 3 };
        var backingListDeals1 = new List<IBucket>
        {
            keyedAggregate1,
            keyedAggregate2
        };

        var backingListDeals2 = new List<IBucket>
        {
            keyedAggregate3
        };
        var bucketAggregate1 = new BucketAggregate()
        {
            Items = backingListDeals1,
            DocCount = 2
        };
        var bucketAggregate2 = new BucketAggregate()
        {
            Items = backingListDeals2,
            DocCount = 2
        };
        var backingDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IAggregate> {{"count_stats", new BucketAggregate
        {
            Items = new List<IBucket>
            {
                new KeyedBucket<object>(new Dictionary<string, IAggregate>{{ "Name2", bucketAggregate1 } })
                {
                    Key = "53986",
                    DocCount = 2
                },
                new KeyedBucket<object>(new Dictionary<string, IAggregate>{{ "Name2", bucketAggregate2 } })
                {
                    Key = "40127",
                    DocCount = 1
                }
            }
        }}};

        var singleBucketAggregate = new SingleBucketAggregate(backingDictionary);

        IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IAggregate> backingDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IAggregate>
        {
            { "count_stats", singleBucketAggregate   }
        };

        return new AggregateDictionary(backingDictionary);
```